# AGM PolyGon - Firestore GeoPoint - InvalidValueError: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Tags: firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, angular-google-maps

Using [AGM PolyGon](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/agmpolygon#source) and [Firestore Geopoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint) to construct a polygon on a google map.

Using the [paths] from AGM, parsing an array of geopoints.

```
@Input() paths: Array<LatLng|LatLngLiteral>|Array<Array<LatLng|LatLngLiteral>> = [];
```

The data in firestore is an array of Geopoints which returns as:

```
[
{ "_lat": -20.2322, "_long": 120.2342 },
{ "_lat": -20.3322, "_long": 120.3342 },
{ "_lat": -21.3322, "_long": 120.3342 },
]
```

Returns the error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidValueError: at index 0: not a LatLng or 
LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
```

**Why is this throwing an error 'not a number' when it is clearly a number?**

Answer (score 0):

it expects `Array<Array<LatLng|LatLngLiteral>>` - while this is an array of objects. for example:

```
[
    new google.maps.LatLng(-20.2322, 120.2342),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-20.2322, 120.2342),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-20.2322, 120.2342)
]
```

Comment: The documentation on firebase says geopoints is returned as an array and the documentation on AGM says they support arrays of objects.

*grumble*

Thanks for the response, hasn't fixed the issue I'm having but it has cleared up that the documentation isn't accurate

Comment: @OtherBarry you probably have to transform the input with `new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)`... when it complains about `InvalidValueError: at index 0: not a LatLng`. so that it explicitly matches the expected signature.

Comment: I checked this and its nearly bang on the money.
AGM expects data as:
[ { someNumber, someNumber} ]
Firebase flat out refuses to store arrays like this and converts it to a string every time.

Working on a work around today; thanks for the direction to look!

Comment: @OtherBarry this would be something alike `Array<Object<Float, Float>>`, while the signature says `Array<LatLng>`... directly loading won't be possible, but transforming the input shouldn't be too difficult; and there basically are only 2-3 possible valid formats to try. as soon as being able to add a single coordinate, it should be clear how the cast has to look alike.

Comment: So it turns out that the AGM input only accepts values in this format:
{ "lat": someNumber, "lng":someNumber }

It refuses to accept any other format.
Becasue firebase works on:
{"_lat": someNumber, "_long": someNumber}

The fix is - dont use Geopoint with AGM; store everything in firebase as an array.

Thanks for the help!